# Need For Speed Hot Pursuit seldom responds to Enter key - very difficult to start the game!

Tags: windows-7, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

I seem to have this issue where NFS HP doesn't respond to the enter key - I have to keep banging it a million times before it accepts ONE input. WTF.

Because of this stupid response I find it impossible to get beyond the first press Enter to continue screen! Sheesh!

Any ideas on how can I get around this ?

(yes, the enter key is working fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured the problem. I had PhraseExpress running in the background and this is causing problems. Closing it resulted in  Enter key being recognised. Why only this particular key and this game - I don't know.