# Need for Speed Hot Pursuit 2010 up arrow key + left arrow key don't work simultaneously

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

While playing Need for speed on my HP Laptop (Windows 7 64-bit), the up arrow key and left arrow key don't work simultaneously. Is there any fix for this issue because I mostly play racing games, if so I would appreciate the help. 
 Up and left arrow do not work simultaneously. the up arrow is used for acceleration and the left to turn. In order to turn I have to switch between up -left-up-left causing the speed to reduce

Comment: That's strange; arrow keys are usually on separate circuits in every keyboard I know of.  Do they work together in other programs?  Or is this just a problem with NFS?

Comment: yes they are separate. Yes they are working in other program

Comment: and after assigning acceleration function to other (a) key .  A+left arrow working find

Comment: Is there something else assigned to the left or up arrow?  Are you pressing anything else while you're steering?

Comment: up key assigned to acceleration and left for steer left. And i press up+left to steer left while acceleration. I dont think anything else is assigned to these key.

Comment: It could be that you have some other program intercepting the key.  See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11286/96435) for a similar problem.